# OVH cdn cache bug when using symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, caching, web, hosting

I have recently deployed my symfony2 project on the production environment.
all it works fine after purging the cache and doing all recommended tasks.
After 1 day, I noticed that all my pages has the same content as the contact page. 
After clearing the cache the website return to be operational, but after a while the bug appear again, so I'm sure now the the root of the problem is the cache but during the deployment I was obliged to rename :

web --> www
vendor/symfony/symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/web.xml --> vendor/symfony/symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/www.xml

because I'm using a shared web hosting.

any suggestions or ideas? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a bug in the hosting provider **CDN cache**,so by disabling it , the website works perfectly.

How to for OVH users :

connect to your hosting by using ssh or ftp, in the root of your website, edit the **".ovhconfig"** and replace **environment=production** by **environment=development**.

Enjoy.